# Charged shots shooting wrong way with controller

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I find that whenever I play Azazel or have any other charged shot item when I release the charge it sometimes just shoots in some random directions other than where I was aiming. I use a controller and use the joystick to shoot. I press in the direction to charge and release to fire. I suspect that the elasticity in the joystick is causing it to snap back to center and a little further, causing it to shoot in the opposite direction on release. Is this a problem anyone else has had? Is it my controller? Is there any way to fix this or should I just start using the buttons instead?

Comment: Has to be a problem with your controller. I also use a controller, but I don't have this problem.

Comment: Do you use the joystick though? I know that you can use the buttons to shoot as well, although I'm not sure how you'd change directions while charging if you have 4 separate buttons. The controller is fairly new and it's a standard Gamestop  Xbox controller.

Comment: Not a real solution here, but you could move the stick back to center with your thumb and not release it to "snap" back. Alternatively you could try to adjust the dead zone on your analog stick, if your controller's software supports it, so that it's too large to snap outside of on its own.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I've tried keeping my thumb on the stick the whole time when moving back to center, but if I move it even a little bit off center, it cuts the shot short and starts a new charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite normal behaviour of joystics in gamepads. Here are a few tips that might help you:

- Do not let go the joystick but rather move it back with your thumb, as suggested by @Chris Hayes in comment
- Use the buttons. It's faster, more reliable, and with some practice you can even switch sides without letting the shot go if you do this fast enough. X360 Controller is quite good for this as it's buttons are round and allow easy "sliding".
- Find an option or a third party software that will allow you to set deadzones for each stick. This will make the stick not respond to weak movements, and with optimal setting you will still be able to use the stick the way you do but without the random shooting.